# How to obtain SHA of the FROM image inside a Dockerfile during the image build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

Inside my container image, I would like to access the SHA of the image my image will be built built from. Hypothetically, if I wanted to drop that into a file, I might do something like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    build-essential

RUN echo ${FROM_SHA} > /etc/source-sha.txt
```

Where there variable `FROM_SHA` has the value of the `ubuntu:16.04`'s SHA. Is it possible to obtain this value within the Dockerfile?

My end goal is to be able to detect if the container image is based on an old version of the tag used in `FROM`.

Two caveats:

1. The image is built using `docker-compose` so something like `docker build --build-arg FROM_SHA=$(<bash commands>)` wouldn't work for this use case.
2. Currently `docker-compose up` just works. There is a desire among the developers on my team to continue this, so a solution involving say a script to update a variable value in a `.env` file which would need to be run manually and/or periodically would not be desired.

Comment: I think you could make an http request to the registry to get the digest sha

Comment: But you already have all the image layers' ids on the container image `docker history` command. Isn't that useful?